# Cannot take image of ArcGIS Map url in background service

Tags: .net, background, arcgis

I would like to take the image of the map in background service (include layers, graphic,...) but unable to make it work with my own code (.NetCore) or some public services such as (tried with 10 or more - paid and free):

https://www.url2png.com/#testdrive
SelectPdf for .NET - Convert from Url to Image - C# / ASP.NET

...

It always returns a blank page while it works with browsers such as firefox/chrome.

The URL I want to make screenshot is
https://siteref.com.au/map/GetImage?type=Planning&reportId=158

My questions are:

1. Is there any configuration that prevent arcgis js files cannot be loaded by background web kit? (I enable cors and other security stuffs at above server in order to making that work)
2. Is there any other good/correct way to make map snapshot image in background service? E.g. I want create an image of an area (with marker, popup,...) daily using a windows service to send to subscribe users

p.s I can make the image from Google Map, Bing Map, and even other pages of my current website (above). It just cannot work with ArcGIS map

Comment: It does not work with Google Maps: https://imgur.com/rWAthY4

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I ran again with Google map URL and had a warning return (Warning: Received createRequest signal on a disposed ResourceObject's NetworkAccessManager. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.)

Comment: I can generate screenshot with bing https://imgur.com/a/VP8DYOv although it said that wkhtmltopdf was not supported. I guess that a completed web engine need to be embedded in background code. Checking and will let you know the result when I got

Answer (score 0):

Please find below link the author of answer. In quick way, I need to use my own server with a real browser to generate image in the foreground.

Quote from Eric

> I spoke to the ArcGIS experts about your question and here's what I gather. ArcGIS   is using WebGL to draw the maps and WebGL uses your GPU to process the imagery it's not a function of the web browser so much as something the web browser hands off to the GPU and is rendered on screen. I don't think Webkit gets a rasterized image back from the WebGL call but it gets rendered directly to the screen.

That's was their idea. I suspect they are correct. There are ways to leverage the ArcGIS  Javscript library to get imagery but it would have to be on your server you couldn't make those calls against someone else's server.

I know that doesn't hep but I hope it answers your question.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wkhtmltopdf-general/zxixypBBLfA